# Can "immediate" be used for people and places

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, collocations

I am a placement consultant and usually hear people use "immediate" (adj) to denote their supervisors and neighbors.

- Can a next door neighbor be an "immediate neighbor"?
- Can a line supervisor be an "immediate supervisor"?

Comment: Most dictionaries should include an entry that indicates that it can.

Comment: Welcome to ELL Stack Exchange! If you looked in a dictionary, and it didn't answer your question, please include that in your question. I checked two dictionaries, and both had "immediate family" as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

to answer your question immediate can be used in both cases.

Immediate neighbor would describe the neighbor directly beside your house.

But your immediate supervisor would be the person directly in charge of you ie: your boss, but NOT your boss's boss.

Hope this helps,

Trevor